# Why do I get this error? Everything seems fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React. I added them to my website with html script tag:

My `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyWebsitewithReact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#2e2e2e">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="developer/">Plugins</a>
    </div>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My `index.js`:

```js
'use strict';

function LikeButton() {
    const [liked, setLiked] = React.useState(false);

    if (liked) {
        return 'You liked this!';
    }

    return React.createElement(
        'button',
        {
            onClick: () => setLiked(true),
        },
        'Like'
    );
}

const rootNode = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootNode);
root.render(React.createElement(LikeButton));
```

This is the error I get :

> Error: Minified React error #299; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=299 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

I have tried to visit and the error is:

> createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element

I checked the documentation and everything seems fine

EDIT:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Your code seems to work ok for me, at least within [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pkm1qu5/)

Comment: Added the photo of the javascript console. Else can be a server problem? The errors are in Italian... (funzione anonima) = (anonymous function) & Codice Globale = Global Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first in your file index.js you need to add in first line:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
```

because without imported these library you can't use elements of React and ReactDOOM.

and in your index.html you need to replace this:

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="js/index.js" type="text/babel" data-type="module"></script>
```

I wish I solved your problem.